# I receive a "could not sign in" error after upgrade to iOS 11.0

Tags: iphone, apple-id, ios, setup

I receive a "could not sign in" error after upgrade to iOS 11.0 Now I can't access my iPhone. What should I do?

Since I have the same problem described above, I am going to describe the steps which I take before the message "could not sign it" appears.

1. I see the screen "Update completed. Your iPhone was updated successfully. There are just few more steps to follow, and then you're finished!"
2. I press the button "continue".
3. An "Apple ID" page appears. Apple credentials should be filled. I am filling my Apple ID and Password and clicking the button "next".
4. A screen appears: "It may take a few minutes..."
5. Terms and Conditions. I press the button "agree".
   And then the message "could not sign in" appears.

Now I can't use my iPhone.

Answer (score 3):

Try switching networks.

If you were using Wi-Fi try another Wi-Fi or switch over to mobile data by disabling Wi-Fi. If you were using your mobile data, try using Wi-Fi.

Often times that helps me out.

If those dont work then you have some options:

1. Restart device
2. Reset network settings (if you can get to them)
3. If resetting device and settings didn't work, check for an iCloud backup or iTunes backup (iCloud preferred). And then erase & restore the iPhone without the backup. If you can sign in with no problem then erase, restore and bring your backup up.

If you can't sign in after the 1st erase and restore without the backup then, call AppleCare and let us know everything that was done and make sure to mention that the restore was done, but it hasn't fixed the issue.

Comment: Strangely enough I was only able to log in to the app store using cellular data, WiFi would always fail. Why is that?

Comment: Then there is a block on the network. Check for a VPN service or one built into the router itself

Comment: Is your ip auto generated or static? That also helps. To further prove if the network is the issue is to try with multiple devices especially Apple devices.

Comment: It's a dynamic ip. Since I had no issues signing in/out of my iCloud account (through Settings), or accessing any site (e.g., Google) over wifi, I find it a bit weird that a VPN would block only the servers responsible for logging into the app store, but I guess it's possible. If I get time I'll sign out of the app store and try it again to see if I can reproduce it; at the moment I'm trying to reproduce a (probably?) unrelated glitch that causes OneDrive to crash. I'm generally well versed with networks but I'm not familiar with how iOS devices in particular interact with corporate networks.

Comment: Try via another wifi network to see if you get similar results.

Answer (score 3):

I tried every method but not okay. So I just click on "forgot passwords or .... " and click on create new one and then click "creat later (like that, not the same)" and it appeared okay with already signed up icloud acc.

Comment: This solution helped me with a renewed phone, I bought it "as new" from a shop but the phone was locked for new users. I was able to sign in with my old ID, but not with a newly created ID for my doughter. I created it online, on as mac or iphone ID, and hardware is restricted to 3 new IDs per phone.